# jasper report blank page in front of excel work sheet

Tags: jasper-reports

I have developed a jasper report with 10 sub reports where 
1.Each sub reports are in separate detail band.
2.placed break element after each sub reports in the detail band for exporting each page in the excel work sheet.
I am getting each element in separate excel sheet but in the first sheet I am getting a blank page with title of the first sub report.
can any one help me in this?
please find  the jrxml of the main report

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-12-11T04:52:39 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TOSMetricsReport" pageWidth="3000" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="2780" leftMargin="200" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="82356077-f8a3-4fb5-92de-af77228a6b21">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CFTransactionalDB"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://sv-clrty14-d3:8080/reportservice/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="superuser"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/organizations/CareFirst/ca_ppm/ReportsCustom/subReports/TOSMetricsReport_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/organizations/CareFirst/ca_ppm/ReportsCustom/subReports/TOSMetricsReport"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet " value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.create.batch.mode.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="background"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="title"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.band.1" value="background"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="link" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band height="332" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" hyperlinkTarget="Top" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-170" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="e8a3ca2e-8d8d-4913-8da7-dfdd33561fc8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" hyperlinkTarget="Top" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-170" y="240" width="170" height="30" uuid="2cbd23e8-4e2c-4107-a0f7-3997ae2f4a2f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cost Center FINApprovers"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["CostCenter"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="30" width="170" height="30" uuid="460205c5-cffd-42bb-bf05-9292f2120c31"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Performance"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["per"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="60" width="170" height="30" uuid="e7425be8-cf87-48e7-8a93-7b1b91f55c40"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["CC Owners & Leads"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["cco"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="90" width="170" height="30" uuid="7173485a-c0ba-4d49-8a19-3ac6b55cff7f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Incomplete key Milestones"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["ikm"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="120" width="170" height="30" uuid="ddf9fea7-bf9a-4f18-a29b-5dee53d2e26c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Deployment Forecast"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["df"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="150" width="170" height="30" uuid="c8fbbc99-d593-4296-b02d-abefd3d795c1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Unfunded"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["uf"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="180" width="170" height="30" uuid="c8fbbc99-d593-4296-b02d-abefd3d795c1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Financials - LT & FY"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["fin"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="210" width="169" height="30" uuid="2c7eb592-f4b4-4f05-95e9-cbfe6882821f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Divisional Plan Milestone"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["dpm"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-170" y="270" width="169" height="30" uuid="f498ca0f-2fdb-4e07-af15-2ed48fb26502"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["RiskScore"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["rs"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="2" width="781" height="30" uuid="622c8818-d378-4b4b-ae4b-7e37ff18c760"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PMO  METRICS]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="10" y="2" width="60" height="39" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="1fe82f93-a1ed-4435-8fa6-87e7ff937fc7"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Roadmap.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="42" width="100" height="1" uuid="5e85b044-1543-44d0-a1f0-2a83e1f8d511">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="33">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="59" height="30" uuid="95611b1b-88c8-47d6-a77d-13a9f69316d3"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Performance.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="100" height="1" uuid="c841c3ff-c3df-4464-8a4c-9ef7d09dffcd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="44">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="5" width="59" height="38" uuid="f8b8bc34-7a99-46c5-bab9-09381626c1bd"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/CC_Owners_&_Leads.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="43" width="100" height="1" uuid="6e9de47b-7f05-4785-8d1f-3457d3d96c1a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="51">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="59" height="48" uuid="02a75b6e-cb02-46d7-873f-4a24b462f2a1"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Incomplete_Key_Milestones.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="100" height="1" uuid="12901493-5c87-40d2-a093-193b20127d0d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="35">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="4" width="59" height="28" uuid="ac55415d-032e-40a0-8e1f-5ea5ae1f2d8d"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Deployment_Forecast.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="34" width="100" height="1" uuid="a9701cb8-1898-426f-abf3-f503bd2c6be7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="30">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="60" height="27" uuid="6d044dc9-ccc1-45dc-8d8d-e85e3ac6146b"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Unfunded.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="100" height="1" uuid="f0a180e0-0c66-4865-8fe4-13a1e78ba69f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="30">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="4" width="59" height="25" uuid="c59580ac-a620-48e7-aa27-3c605b7284a3"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Financials - LT & FY.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="100" height="1" uuid="0894fa3a-1f37-4747-a501-aef8fe997482">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="31">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="60" height="28" uuid="b4aa0a9a-1024-4fbe-8ed7-0e7feb418c01"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Divisional_Plan_Milestone.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="1" uuid="6699d708-6447-4458-bd25-fe064bf990b2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="32">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="1" width="60" height="28" uuid="9fd474cf-ac38-4de2-a644-ccc9c88fc287"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/CostCenterFINApprovers.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="100" height="1" uuid="a077ff9d-f999-4f95-89ad-d7e909360465">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="31">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="e8ae422b-705a-4c48-badd-d955fa7f6d47"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Riskss.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="1" uuid="f5cd0f71-0ff6-411c-9e2f-9d26a07c547d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: solved by giving  the print when expression of band containing the break element .<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
    <textField>
     <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="1" uuid="ddf8561d-a742-4ee5-9504-4e2b4a979735">
      <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
      <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
      <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
     </reportElement>

Comment: I have moved your comment into answer (community wiki, no rep points), consider accepting it to close question.

Answer (score 0):

Moved @harun prasu comment into answer (community wiki)

solved by giving the print when expression of band containing the break element .

```
 <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==0]]></printWhenExpression>  
 <textField>
   <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="1" uuid="ddf8561d-a742-4ee5-9504-4e2b4a979735"> 
   <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/> 
   <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/> 
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/> 
   </reportElement>
```